# Expressing primes $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ in the form $p = x^2 + xy + y^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-number-theory

Fermat famously showed that the only primes $p$ of the form $x^2 + y^2$ are the primes such that $p \equiv 1 \mod{4}$. Furthermore, we now know “effective” versions of Fermat's theorem, i.e. given a prime $p$ such that $p \equiv 1 \mod{4}$, we know how to find integers $x$, $y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = p$ in time polynomial in $\log p$ (see, for example section 4.5 in [1]). I would like an analogous theory for primes of the form $x^2 + xy + y^2$. In other words, I would like a precise characterization of which primes $p$ can be expressed in this form (**EDIT:** The [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371622/expressing-primes-p-equiv-1-pmod-3-in-the-form-p-x2-xy-y2#comment939751_371622) explain that these are the primes $\not\equiv 2\mod 3$), as well as an efficient algorithm to obtain such a factorization given $p$.

1. *Shoup, Victor*, [A computational introduction to number theory and algebra](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/computational-introduction-to-number-theory-and-algebra/8C43512C31D9FDE058E360441175966C), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-51644-0/hbk). xvii, 580 p. (2009). [ZBL1196.11002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1196.11002).

Comment: These are well known to be the prime rational integers which do not remain prime in the ring of Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega$ is a primitive complex cube root of unity. These are the rational primes congruent to $1$ (mod $3$), and the rational prime $3$.

Comment: Ok, that's a great start! Given such a prime $p$, how do I express it as $x^2 + xy + y^2$?

Comment: There's a difference between a theoretical explanation and a computationally efficient method. Anyway, the ring of Eisenstein integers is a Euclidean ring, which helps.

Comment: gp-pari code:
$$ $$
**eisen(p,v) = v=abs(qflll([lift((sqrt(Mod(-3,p))+1)/2),p;1,0])[1,]); if(v*v~>p, [vecmin(v),abs(v[1]-v[2])], v)**
$$ $$
For example, **eisen(100000000003)** returns [103166, 251761].

Comment: Hi Noam, this is fantastic! Thanks so much for your response. Can you give a brief high-level overview of how this code works? I assume it's related to the fact that $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is the norm over the Eisenstein integers...

Comment: (There’s also a “formula” for such $x$ and $y$, namely $x - y \zeta_3 = J(\chi, \chi) = \sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}_p} \chi(a) \chi(1-a)$, where $\chi: \mathbb{F}_p^\times\to \{1, \zeta_3, \zeta_3^2\}$ is a cubic character mod $p$.)

Comment: @Gautam: Basically yes; (sqrt(-3) + 1)/2 is the ratio x:y if xx+xy+yy=0.  It's essentially Cornacchia's algorithm, with the Euclidean algorithm replaced by the closely related reduction of a 2-dim. lattice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton!

Comment: @alpoge as you know that's a beautiful formula but not well suited for computation -- imagine doing it for p=100000000003 (it's even slower than just trying all x up to sqrt(p)).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies certainly agreed!! I just figured I’d add that bit of trivia in given that the question was answered.

Comment: About the computational aspect, if $x<y$ have $\sim 500$ decimal digits and I know $p$ and I know (from an oracle) that $p$ is prime, can I compute $x,y$ in reasonable time? I guess not.

Comment: @YCor Actually you can!  You just need a cube root of unity mod $p$,
which is easy in random polynomial time, and even possible deterministically
thanks to Schoof's algorithm (which is related with **alpoge**'s comment).
Then Euclid or 2-dimensional LLL is polynomial time.  For example,
the smallest 500 digit prime is $10^{499} + 153$, which happens to be
1 mod 3, and "eisen" takes only 12 milliseconds to find its $(x,y)$.

Comment: [2463505687802154058859226730108383571591600256629173176364980024555626670349497123082936620270065106374169122856933117712904951390428449265056103980972775860781270581881580532542195873409432401268688833706520165493628574413068924000927599285073761949, 1102418271211271989374012922279714325115202464904081123218798301995385992754729584967829222778046361602101500269511074106202422438370926118997383768231376869226103315918023605989878251994931215507091583589312445322666942269948872277385599352796657552]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722377/p-x2-xy-y2-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-text-mod-3

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies If you convert one or more of your comments into an answer, the OP can accept it, and then this won't continue to get flagged as an unanswered question.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Is this pari code the same as yours:


**n=10^499+153;bnfisintnorm(bnfinit(x^2+x+1),n)**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an elaboration of the answer that Noam Elkies provided in the comments.

Suppose that $p=x^2 + xy + y^2$.  Then note that $x$ and $y$ are small relative to $p$ (at most half as many digits).  Note also that if $\zeta \not\equiv 1\pmod p$ satisfies $\zeta^3 \equiv 1\pmod p$ then $\zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, so
$$(x - \zeta y)(x - \zeta^2 y) = x^2 - (\zeta+\zeta^2)xy + \zeta^3 y^2 \equiv x^2 + xy + y^2 \equiv p \equiv 0 \pmod p.$$
Therefore either $x \equiv \zeta y \pmod p$ or $x \equiv \zeta^2 y \pmod p$; in the latter case we have $\zeta x \equiv y \pmod p$.  This means that in the 2-dimensional integer lattice generated by the vectors $(1,\zeta)$ and $(0,p)$, there is an unusually short vector $(y,x)$ or $(x,y)$, which can be found by lattice-basis reduction as long as we have $\zeta$.

It remains to find $\zeta$.  Formally, we can write
$$\zeta := {\sqrt{-3} - 1 \over 2},$$
and it is easy to check that if we can find a square root of $-3$ modulo $p$ then this formula does indeed give us a cube root of unity modulo $p$.  But computing the square root can be done using the [Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) or [Schoof's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999286/502981).

Comment: I should remark that $x$ could be slightly larger than $\sqrt p$ if $y$ is negative. But if $p = x^2 - xy + y^2 = (x-y)^2 + xy$ for some $x>0$ and $y>0$ then $|x-y| < \sqrt p$. So neither $x$ nor $y$ can be much larger than $\sqrt p$, because then $xy$ would be larger than $p$.